# Flutter overfloxBox is not working for me

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile-application

I need the maximum available width of the media so that the image doesn't overflow and cause a rendering issue.Here is my code:

```
Expanded(
              child: OverflowBox(
                maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: (infos.length.toDouble() / 2).toInt(),
                    itemBuilder: (_, i) {
                      int a = 2 * i;
                      int b = 2 * i + 1;

                      return Row(
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            height: 170,
                            width: 200,
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                              image: DecorationImage(
                                image: AssetImage(infos[a]["img"]),
                              ),
                              boxShadow: [
                                BoxShadow(
                                  blurRadius: 3,
                                  offset: const Offset(5, 5),
                                  color: customColor.AppColor.gradientSecond
                                      .withOpacity(0.1),
                                ),
                                BoxShadow(
                                  blurRadius: 3,
                                  offset: const Offset(-5, -5),
                                  color: customColor.AppColor.gradientSecond
                                      .withOpacity(0.1),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            child: Center(
                              child: Align(
                                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                child: Text(
                                  infos[a]["title"],
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 20,
                                    color: customColor.AppColor.homePageTitle,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            height: 170,
                            width: 200,
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                              image: DecorationImage(
                                image: AssetImage(infos[b]["img"]),
                              ),
                              boxShadow: [
                                BoxShadow(
                                  blurRadius: 3,
                                  offset: const Offset(5, 5),
                                  color: customColor.AppColor.gradientSecond
                                      .withOpacity(0.1),
                                ),
                                BoxShadow(
                                  blurRadius: 3,
                                  offset: const Offset(-5, -5),
                                  color: customColor.AppColor.gradientSecond
                                      .withOpacity(0.1),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            child: Center(
                              child: Align(
                                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                child: Text(
                                  infos[b]["title"],
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 20,
                                    color: customColor.AppColor.homePageTitle,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      );
                    }),
              ),
            ),
```

here you can see that I have given the width of the image. The images overflow because the parent container has some padding all around it. to solve this I have used overflowbox and taken maximum available width. But is doesn't work. i am still facing rendering issue.
here is the issue:

***════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════ The following assertion was thrown during layout: A RenderFlex overflowed by 40 pixels on the right.
The relevant error-causing widget was Row home_page.dart:321 You can inspect this widget using the 'Inspect Widget' button in the VS Code notification. The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.horizontal. The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.
Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the children of the RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead of being sized to their natural size. This is considered an error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space, consider clipping it with a ClipRect widget before putting it in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex, like a ListView.
The specific RenderFlex in question is: RenderFlex#ea0e1 relayoutBoundary=up5 OVERFLOWING ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════ Reloaded 1 of 667 libraries in 429ms (compile: 26 ms, reload: 100 ms, reassemble: 252 ms).***

How to solve this problem?

Comment: try to remove fixed width like `width: 200,`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove fixed width like `width:200` and wrap both containers with Expanded.

Comment: I know i have given the containers a fixed width. But that's the reason I have used overflow box.
what do you suggest without giving a fixed width

Comment: I have tried using the expanded widget to wrap the containers and it works. Thank you